# Get the total sum hours in a column SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, calculated-columns, hour

[Sql Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f748a/2)

I have this result table

```
 Id     Hours
 -----   -----
 1       09:00
 2       09:30
 3       10:00
 4       10:30
 5       11:00
 6       11:30
 7       12:00
 8       12:30
 9       13:00
10       13:30
11       14:00
12       14:30
13       15:00
14       15:30
15       16:00
16       16:30
17       17:00
18       17:30
19       18:00
```

I need to get the total sum hours, for example from 09:00 to 18:00 there is a total of :

> 9

hours, I need to get this sum of hours

Comment: Do you mean max(Hours) - min(Hours)?

Comment: I want to get the total hour between two hours, for example from 9:00 to 12:00 there is a total of 3 hours

Comment: and what if the last time is 17:30?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table schema `hour` is `varchar`, you need to cast as time, then do the calculation

```
SELECT  datediff(hour,min(cast(hour as time)),max(cast(hour as time)))
FROM Timetable
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f748a/17)

**NOTE**

I would suggest your `hour` column as `datetime` or `time` instead of `varchar`. because `hour` column intention is time.

---

**EDIT**

If your time is `9:00 to 17:30`, you can try to use `datediff` minute to get the total diff minutes then divide 60 to get hours.

```
SELECT datediff(minute,min(cast(hour as time)),max(cast(hour as time))) / CAST(60 as float)
FROM Timetable
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6e005cdfad4eca3ff7c4c92ef14cc9c7

Comment: and what if the last time is 17:30?!

Answer (score 1):

use `datediff` function

```
select datediff(hour,min(h),max(h)) from
(

select CAST(hour AS TIME) as h from Timetable
  ) as  t
```

strongly disagreed to put time value in varchar ,so it is better change your data type from varchar to time

Comment: your data in varchar that's why its shows 1 btw i sidited answer

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @a time = '13:00',@b time = '17:30'  --- Here you can give time, what you need.
select distinct convert(varchar(20)
, datediff(MINUTE,@a,@b) / 60) 
  + ':' + 
  convert(varchar(20), datediff(MINUTE,@a,@b) % 60) 
from #Timetable 
where hour in (@a,@b)
```

For your SQL Fiddle Sample Data.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you need to use `datediff()`.  However, you should be doing the `datediff()` in minutes or seconds and then converting to hours:

```
SELECT datediff(minute, min(cast(hour as time)), max(cast(hour as time))) / 60.0
FROM Timetable;
```

This will handle the case where the number of hours is not an exact number of hours.